# C# Webservice Client: How to avoid causing service to throw SystemException (appears to be an xml namespacing issue)

Tags: c#, web-services, soap-client

I am attempting to consume a SOAP based web service from a proprietary, JBoss based application from C# (via service reference), but the server keeps returning a SystemException.

I used fiddler to capture the webservice calls from the vendor's flash front end and from the C# and compared / tweaked them in soapUI until I tracked the difference down to a name spacing issue.

Basically to take a non-working message and make it work, I modify `<addPackageItems xmlns="...">` to `<tns:addPackageItems xmlns:tns="...">` and `</addPackageItems>` to `</tns:addPackageItems>`

My question is basically how can I make this work by making a modification in the client ( my C# code)?  I hate to to be so generic but to be honest I don't know why the namespace is required to avoid the error on the server, so I didn't want to ask how modify my C# code to produce a name space for the xmlns on `addPackageItems` if there is an alternative, better solution.

### Misc. Information

The C# code is using code generated by adding a service reference under Visual Studio 2012.  I can provide the calling code; I'm not convinced its really useful without having the WSDL available and I'm not sure I'm allowed to provide them under our agreement (I've never seen it).

### Non-working SOAP message

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<s:Body>
  <addPackageItems xmlns="http://www.docfinity.com/webservices/BpmClientWebServices/">
    <processInstanceId>87499</processInstanceId>
    <packageItemDto>
      <packageItemName>document</packageItemName>
        <properties>
         <name>documentId</name>
         <stringValue>0c7eb1cb3a94986f013ae5c4d8777fde</stringValue>
        </properties>
        <type>DocFinityDocument</type>
      </packageItemDto>
    </addPackageItems>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

### Working soap message

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<s:Body>
  <tns:addPackageItems xmlns:tns="http://www.docfinity.com/webservices/BpmClientWebServices/">
    <processInstanceId>87499</processInstanceId>
    <packageItemDto>
      <packageItemName>document</packageItemName>
        <properties>
         <name>documentId</name>
         <stringValue>0c7eb1cb3a94986f013ae5c4d8777fde</stringValue>
        </properties>
        <type>DocFinityDocument</type>
      </packageItemDto>
    </tns:addPackageItems>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 XML documents are almost completely different - as result on works another does not.

- `<addPackageItems xmlns="http://www...` means "this and all child nodes without prefix will have this namespace"
- `<tns:addPackageItems xmlns:tns="http://www...` means "this and node all child nodes with `tns` prefix have this namespace, nodes without prefix have previous default namespace.

So in 2 documents `<processInstanceId>` nodes (and siblings/child nodes) have different namespaces - "http://www.docfinity.com/webs..." in first one, empty in the second one.

You need to be careful to create nodes in correct namespace. The way to specify namespaces depends on a way you create XML.

Comment: "The way to specify namespaces depends on a way you create XML." -- Correct, and that's why I specifically stated that I'm using C# and added a service reference to the WSDL under Visual Studio 2012.  That creates all sorts of classes automatically which is why I'm unsure of how to modify and why I was very specific that it has the be a client modification as the server side isn't under my control (technically the server is, but the software is proprietary so I can't change it)